# <Raw> tag in scapy, how do I decode the content?

Tags: python-2.7, tcp, scapy

I used Scapy to sniff for TCP packets in an attempt to get HTML code from the response.

```
>>>A = sniff(filter='tcp')
```

(Then I refreshed a webpage)

```
>>>A
<Sniffed: TCP:148 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>
>>>A.show()
0000 Ether / IP / TCP 192.168.0.2:60210 > 74.125.28.95:www S
```

(obviously there were more than this, this is just an example)

```
>>>A[28]
<Ether  dst=00:24:1d:20:a6:1b src=e8:de:27:55:17:f3 type=IPv4 |<IP  version=4L ihl=5L tos=0x0 len=1056 id=49239 flags= frag=0L ttl=45 proto=tcp chksum=0xa1fa src=74.125.28.95 dst=192.168.0.2 options=[] |<TCP  sport=www dport=60210 seq=956108121 ack=2048727264 dataofs=8L reserved=0L flags=PA window=343 chksum=0x3df5 urgptr=0 options=[('NOP', None), ('NOP', None), ('Timestamp', (644692201, 2737592))] |<Raw  load='\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xed\x97\xd9\x92\xa2H\x14\x86\xef\xeb)\xb8\xab\xaa\x9e\xa6Hp\x01\xec\x9ba\x11AE\\(\x15o\x0cD6E@6\x95\x89y\xf7\x01\xb5jz&\xc2\xb15\xaa\'\xc4\xea\x1b3\x0e\'3I\xfe/\xf2?G\xe4\x0b\xe4\xa8\x91\xed\xc2\xfa6\x82\xbe \x0f\xbf\x1b\x9e\x1b\xc1\x86\xaa\xe9\xd0\x1f\x0f\x10t\x8cV\xb6\xb3\xabA\x8f\x03/\x0e\xb2\x04\xe3\xcdu\xa8\x1bx\x8f\xdf\xdef\x84\xd1\xce\xd1k\x90\xeb\x05+\xd5y\x7f\xba\xd1m\xd3\x8ajP\t\x80\xfcY\x18h5\xc8\xf14\xd5y\xfa\xf7NP;\x9f\xf9\xf8\xfc\xf5\x9f\xf9<\x9de\xe1\xf7l\x1c8OV\x14\xf95\x04\xc9\xdf\x10\xbe\x98a\x94\x9d^{\xd1\xbc\x15\x12"\xe1~\x95\x96\xad\xf2\x03\x0fI\xaa\x88\xa3\xaf\x93R\x02\xef\xe4\xb0\xd9ap\x97K\xdd\x81\xb8\x96\xfb\xc3\x84Nz\x82\x86\xa68\xa1M\xa7\xb1Gk;\xe1e\xe3\x19\x06\xf6\x9c\x9d<\xfb\x86\xe8\xe9q\x1f>>\xe7\x07\x8f];\xdf\x13\x0eT\xd7\xcc\xbe\xf2\xf57\x80\x02\x00\x03\xac\xcc}\xcd\x02\xb4\x9e\x05h\x9d\xdb\x07\x18\xa0\x00\x9c\xfd\xd0\xc7\x80\xcd\x02\xe6\x90a\xaaY\x86\xc1\xf7\x01\x85c\x00\xa6p\x8e\xfb\xf6\xf0\xe7\x03rD\xf0I\xe4\xd7\xb3<\x80\xeb\xb1\xb8T`X\x1e\xec\xea[]\xe8\x98\x17\xc9\x0fr\xf9\xc1Aq\x80\x96\xd0\xc3X\xc1\xe0\xec\xa7\xb4\x0f2\xb5\x0f#K\x1dG\xe6@\x04\xe4x\xaaGVx\xf9\x88\xe9\x90\xc4P\xec8V\xf2\xb1~|C\x86\x96\xcdG\x0e\xe4B\xfe\xcd\xebg^\x99\xf2Yf\'i\xf5u3v\xd4\xe0\x1a^\xab\xc0!\x16K\x11%$G\xeau\x88f\xdbTCv\x87\xf5\x88Po\xa0\xf8\xcc`\xc7J\x7f\xbax\r\x83\xf42^\x85\xba.7$=9\x9cb\xae9!\xe6\xa2A\x18ms\xa1\xd4\xbdx[\xb0\xab\x92\xd8z\xe4\xaa+=\xd4\x7f\x14\xd8@u\xc3\x8f\xf1\xb7\xb7\x9dN\xf8[\x9e\xbe\xdc\xdf\xc2l\xd5\x1e\x1a\x89D\x9e:\x974c\xe5D\xe4\xacD\xcc\xf9\xe6V\xa2\x1b\xect\x01\\\xd1\xa6I\xa3k\x99\xd3%\xba\x99\xb70\x0b\\x_r>\xa0t\xb8/\xd4\xfe\xbe\x90G\xfd\xe9k-\xa8\xe8\xb2\x16\xbcj\x17\\~\xe9\x0e\xaa\xf6\xcf\xb7\xa2\xd3\xb5\xe3}\xa7S\xb8.\xad\x1d\xdf\x01\x93X\xdd\x11P\x95\xa7\x15\x96^\x9b\xba@\xf1X\xeat$\x8a\xe7:U\xdaN\x06\x81\xaa,\x17V\xa2\xf7y\xa5x6tC\x922\x05\xef\x84\n,}\xe7W\'\xf4\x03\xc0\xaa\xe7k\xc6@_\xd93\xcf\x99\x9f$\xf7\xfd\x84\x0f\xa9\x1c\x8c\xa3l\x86\x92\xc5\xf6\xd7X2\xf3\x1b}y\x82\xcffa\xf1\x8c\xe8&\xc5\xe5Z\x9c\x85\xca\xac\xdc\r^\'\xa3t\xe8W\xb9\xc8o\x10\xf7kI7\t\x81\x918wTj.\x81\x01\xc8t4U\x1c\xb7\x8aS\xda\xa75\';R\x1d[\xbb\xba\xa1\x85\x84\xfd\xfa\xff\xeek\x85\xab:[\xc3\x97\x87|\x8bX\x87\xe3\x99\xa0\xcb\xbc\x1c\xb8=\xbeZ\xc7\x89F\xd4\xf7K\x8e\xa5Y\xb1\xcf4;\x1b"\xaa\\z\x85\xfeO\x7f*\x98\xbem\x7f[&\xf1\x88,{l\xac\x12-\x83j\x93\x06\\\xbf\x03\x8b*\x18\x07\x91Z,w\xb6\xbe\x19)\xc1h\xa2U\x80@X-\xfc\xb2?\xd0\x9f\xc0\xa5\xce\xf7\xbc\xe7\xb8]\x87L\xc4\x9as\x1c\xf5\xbaM\xab\xdd\xf2A:\x8f\xe4\xc4\x13q\x85_\x979\x93\x17\x00F\x13AW\xd3Z\x80k\xf6\x8agM7%j\x19D\xe6\x96$\x17+\xa5\x91L\xb7\xa9\x12o\xe6h\xf0z\xbf~tS\xe2o\xcd\x1d\xc6\x85\x8bJ\xb8(\xd5Sg\xec\xaf\x87\xe3~\xcb\xfbeBWw\xb9\xe7\xd8\xbd\xcd\xfb\xc0B\xc2\xa4"6V\xa85\xa1\xb1\x96:\x0e\x83\x0e1\x1akT\xf1\\\xe9\xb6U\x96\xc6-y\xa2t;Q\x03\xdd\x89\xf4Ti\x0e\xd6\xd9\t\xee\xd7\xa6n\x9bF\xa3\xd7\x8aS1v\xb5\x004i\x1c\x05\x1b\x15\x9bw\x8b\xd4<\xfd\x05\xf0Y\xff2\xe8!\x00\x00' |>>>>
```

The Raw tag contained this:

```
<Raw  load='\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xed\x97\xd9\x92\xa2H\x14\x86\xef\xeb)\xb8\xab\xaa\x9e\xa6Hp\x01\xec\x9ba\x11AE\\(\x15o\x0cD6E@6\x95\x89y\xf7\x01\xb5jz&\xc2\xb15\xaa\'\xc4\xea\x1b3\x0e\'3I\xfe/\xf2?G\xe4\x0b\xe4\xa8\x91\xed\xc2\xfa6\x82\xbe \x0f\xbf\x1b\x9e\x1b\xc1\x86\xaa\xe9\xd0\x1f\x0f\x10t\x8cV\xb6\xb3\xabA\x8f\x03/\x0e\xb2\x04\xe3\xcdu\xa8\x1bx\x8f\xdf\xdef\x84\xd1\xce\xd1k\x90\xeb\x05+\xd5y\x7f\xba\xd1m\xd3\x8ajP\t\x80\xfcY\x18h5\xc8\xf14\xd5y\xfa\xf7NP;\x9f\xf9\xf8\xfc\xf5\x9f\xf9<\x9de\xe1\xf7l\x1c8OV\x14\xf95\x04\xc9\xdf\x10\xbe\x98a\x94\x9d^{\xd1\xbc\x15\x12"\xe1~\x95\x96\xad\xf2\x03\x0fI\xaa\x88\xa3\xaf\x93R\x02\xef\xe4\xb0\xd9ap\x97K\xdd\x81\xb8\x96\xfb\xc3\x84Nz\x82\x86\xa68\xa1M\xa7\xb1Gk;\xe1e\xe3\x19\x06\xf6\x9c\x9d<\xfb\x86\xe8\xe9q\x1f>>\xe7\x07\x8f];\xdf\x13\x0eT\xd7\xcc\xbe\xf2\xf57\x80\x02\x00\x03\xac\xcc}\xcd\x02\xb4\x9e\x05h\x9d\xdb\x07\x18\xa0\x00\x9c\xfd\xd0\xc7\x80\xcd\x02\xe6\x90a\xaaY\x86\xc1\xf7\x01\x85c\x00\xa6p\x8e\xfb\xf6\xf0\xe7\x03rD\xf0I\xe4\xd7\xb3<\x80\xeb\xb1\xb8T`X\x1e\xec\xea[]\xe8\x98\x17\xc9\x0fr\xf9\xc1Aq\x80\x96\xd0\xc3X\xc1\xe0\xec\xa7\xb4\x0f2\xb5\x0f#K\x1dG\xe6@\x04\xe4x\xaaGVx\xf9\x88\xe9\x90\xc4P\xec8V\xf2\xb1~|C\x86\x96\xcdG\x0e\xe4B\xfe\xcd\xebg^\x99\xf2Yf\'i\xf5u3v\xd4\xe0\x1a^\xab\xc0!\x16K\x11%$G\xeau\x88f\xdbTCv\x87\xf5\x88Po\xa0\xf8\xcc`\xc7J\x7f\xbax\r\x83\xf42^\x85\xba.7$=9\x9cb\xae9!\xe6\xa2A\x18ms\xa1\xd4\xbdx[\xb0\xab\x92\xd8z\xe4\xaa+=\xd4\x7f\x14\xd8@u\xc3\x8f\xf1\xb7\xb7\x9dN\xf8[\x9e\xbe\xdc\xdf\xc2l\xd5\x1e\x1a\x89D\x9e:\x974c\xe5D\xe4\xacD\xcc\xf9\xe6V\xa2\x1b\xect\x01\\\xd1\xa6I\xa3k\x99\xd3%\xba\x99\xb70\x0b\\x_r>\xa0t\xb8/\xd4\xfe\xbe\x90G\xfd\xe9k-\xa8\xe8\xb2\x16\xbcj\x17\\~\xe9\x0e\xaa\xf6\xcf\xb7\xa2\xd3\xb5\xe3}\xa7S\xb8.\xad\x1d\xdf\x01\x93X\xdd\x11P\x95\xa7\x15\x96^\x9b\xba@\xf1X\xeat$\x8a\xe7:U\xdaN\x06\x81\xaa,\x17V\xa2\xf7y\xa5x6tC\x922\x05\xef\x84\n,}\xe7W\'\xf4\x03\xc0\xaa\xe7k\xc6@_\xd93\xcf\x99\x9f$\xf7\xfd\x84\x0f\xa9\x1c\x8c\xa3l\x86\x92\xc5\xf6\xd7X2\xf3\x1b}y\x82\xcffa\xf1\x8c\xe8&\xc5\xe5Z\x9c\x85\xca\xac\xdc\r^\'\xa3t\xe8W\xb9\xc8o\x10\xf7kI7\t\x81\x918wTj.\x81\x01\xc8t4U\x1c\xb7\x8aS\xda\xa75\';R\x1d[\xbb\xba\xa1\x85\x84\xfd\xfa\xff\xeek\x85\xab:[\xc3\x97\x87|\x8bX\x87\xe3\x99\xa0\xcb\xbc\x1c\xb8=\xbeZ\xc7\x89F\xd4\xf7K\x8e\xa5Y\xb1\xcf4;\x1b"\xaa\\z\x85\xfeO\x7f*\x98\xbem\x7f[&\xf1\x88,{l\xac\x12-\x83j\x93\x06\\\xbf\x03\x8b*\x18\x07\x91Z,w\xb6\xbe\x19)\xc1h\xa2U\x80@X-\xfc\xb2?\xd0\x9f\xc0\xa5\xce\xf7\xbc\xe7\xb8]\x87L\xc4\x9as\x1c\xf5\xbaM\xab\xdd\xf2A:\x8f\xe4\xc4\x13q\x85_\x979\x93\x17\x00F\x13AW\xd3Z\x80k\xf6\x8agM7%j\x19D\xe6\x96$\x17+\xa5\x91L\xb7\xa9\x12o\xe6h\xf0z\xbf~tS\xe2o\xcd\x1d\xc6\x85\x8bJ\xb8(\xd5Sg\xec\xaf\x87\xe3~\xcb\xfbeBWw\xb9\xe7\xd8\xbd\xcd\xfb\xc0B\xc2\xa4"6V\xa85\xa1\xb1\x96:\x0e\x83\x0e1\x1akT\xf1\\\xe9\xb6U\x96\xc6-y\xa2t;Q\x03\xdd\x89\xf4Ti\x0e\xd6\xd9\t\xee\xd7\xa6n\x9bF\xa3\xd7\x8aS1v\xb5\x004i\x1c\x05\x1b\x15\x9bw\x8b\xd4<\xfd\x05\xf0Y\xff2\xe8!\x00\x00' |>>>>
```

What type of encoding is this? & How do I decode it?

Answer (score 0):

`0x1f8b0800`, the beginning of the `Raw` field, if the beginning of a `tar` file (http://digital-forensics.sans.org/media/hex_file_and_regex_cheat_sheet.pdf)

Might want to try untarring the contents of the hexdump